# QT creator : error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, qt, linker

I'm trying to run this simple code in QT Creator.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    const int SENTINEL = 0;
    int main() {
        cout<<"This program adds a list of numbers "<<endl;
        cout<<"Use "<<SENTINEL<<" to signal the end."<<endl;
        int total = 0;
        while(true) {
            int value;
            cout<<" ? ";
            cin>>value;
            if(value == SENTINEL) break;
            total += value;
        }
        cout<<"The total is "<<total<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

But I keep on getting this two issues.

1. error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
2. error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And the full description that I get is this. Inside Compile Output.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "Main()", referenced
>   from:
>         Main(int, char**) in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation) make: ***
>   [simple-project.app/Contents/MacOS/simple-project] Error 1 00:04:36:
>   The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2. Error while
>   building/deploying project simple-project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 clang
>   64bit) When executing step "Make" 00:04:36: Elapsed time: 00:27.

Comment: I pasted your code into a main.cpp and it works fine here. Is actually more code involved in your case?

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your code, if you copy/paste it into a new project it compiles just fine. The problem is that some .obj file or Makefile file has problems in it. These files basically contain the compiled code that hasn't been linked yet. These files aren't always updated at each compilation, only when the source code that generated them has changed. This means that when the project settings have been changed (which you apparently did), these files aren't necessarily changed to fit the new settings, so it generates errors. This system is made to make the compilation faster, but can sometimes be a nuisance, like in your case. To solve your problem, simply delete the folder which contains these files and the compiled .exe file. With Qt Creator this folder usually has a name that looks something like `build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Release`. When you delete the folder, all the files will be deleted so the compiler will have to generate new files with the correct settings this time.